# JQuery animate div's width onclick

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-animate, width

I have no idea why this doesn't work.

JQuery:

```
$("#foldit").click(function () {
    $("foldit").animate({"width": "165px"}, "fast");
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its because you have missed `#` in your selector.

Just try to use the `this` reference inside that click event to achieve what you want,

```
$("#foldit").click(function () {
    $(this).animate({"width": "165px"}, "fast");
});
```

As per your new requirement you can try like this,

```
$('#foldit').click( function() {
    var toggleWidth = $(this).width() == 165 ? "100px" : "165px";
    $(this).animate({ width: toggleWidth });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CUZX4/1/)

Comment: Is there any way I can make it that when I click for the 2nd time it will change back to its original width?

Comment: @ShaulBar-Lev Try out my new update.

Comment: I get the concept but on my page it doesn't really work.

Comment: I click once but nothing happens, than on the 2nd click it runs.

Comment: @ShaulBar-Lev Can you make a demo of it.? so that we could fix your issue easily. :)

Comment: Nevermind, I worked it out myself. Last request: how to specify the animation's speed?

Comment: @ShaulBar-Lev you can replace that "fast" with some thing like "slow", "medium" or even you can specify the speed in milliseconds like 200 or anything.

Answer (score 2):

You missed `'#'` in the selector and alternatively you can use it like this as well

```
$("#foldit").click(function () {
    $(this).animate({"width": "165px"}, "fast");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this)` in the place of `$("foldit")`